# How does let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper") work

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In the code block below, I am having trouble understanding `let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper")`.

```
let vegetable = "red pepper"

switch vegetable {
    case "celery":
        let vegetableComment = "Add some raisins and make ants on a log."
    case "cucumber", "watercress":
        let vegetableComment = "That would make a good tea sandwhich"
    case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
        let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)"
    default:
        let vegetableComment = "Everything tastes good in soup."
}
```

> Console output
>
> **vegetableComment:** Is it a spicy red pepper

It seems like the following logic is happening.

```
x = vegetable
if (x's suffix == 'pepper') 
    run case
```

Can someone explain this better for me?

Comment: looks like an inline lambda

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`vegetable` is an implicit `String`. It's the same as you would write:

```
var vegetable: String = "red pepper"
```

`hasSuffix` is declared as `func hasSuffix(suffix: String) -> Bool` an therefore returns a `Bool`. The `where` keyword specifies additional requirements, and can only be used in `switch` statements.

Because all of this is suffused, the `vegetable` variable is assigned to x (`let x`).

You can read more about the `where` and `switch` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_153).

Comment: I've read the reference at apple site but how does somebody access the result of switch vegetable? Is switch a function? Or does the Code in the matching case just run? ( sorry for the nooobie question )

Comment: It would make far more sense if it read: vegatable.hasSuffix("pepper")

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no reason to use `let x` in this scenario. `case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):` can simply be replaced with `case vegetable where vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper")`. In this scenario, an extra variable `x` is declared which copies `vegetable`. This is useless, and arguable reduces readability, even if you renamed `x` to `vegetable` as well.

Using `let` in a switch statement case is useful in other cases, such as when the "argument" (vegetable) is not a variable, e.g. `switch(getVegetableName())` , or in the case where the "argument" is a tuple, and needs to be unpacked, such as in

```swift
let vegetableNameAndCountry = ("Sweet Potato", "United States")

switch(vegetableNameAndCountry) {
   case (let vegetable, let country) where country == "Tanzania":
       print("This \(vegetable) comes from a country north of Kenya")
   case ("Sweet Potato", _): // Note here I ignore the country, and don't even bother creating a constant for it
       print("Sweet sweet potatoes")
   default:
       print("We don't care about this vegetable")
}
```